# How to execute .sh file with php via website

Tags: php, sh

I'm trying to exec file from .php file via website

First am trying :

```
<?php

exec('bash create_user.sh '.$_POST['password'].' '.$_POST['username']);

exec('bash create_user.sh 123456 user');

?>
```

And nothing done!

Secound am trying :

```
<?php

shell_exec('bash create_user.sh '.$_POST['password'].' '.$_POST['username']);

shell_exec('bash create_user.sh 123456 user');

?>
```

And nothing done!

how can I do this. thnx.

Comment: if you execute from the shell ./bash create_user.sh 123456 user the script work fine?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Yes, fine

Comment: and php have the correct file permissions?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Yeah, chmod +x to both of them [.sh & .php]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your sh add as first line

```
 #!/bin/sh
```

then call in php like this

```
    if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['username'])) {
        shell_exec('./create_user.sh '. $_POST['password'] . ' ' . $_POST['username']);
    } else {
    echo 'You must send user and pass';
    }
```

And give to the web server user write/execute permissions.